# Obsolete/erroneous code in convolutional_mlp.py at DeepLearningTutorials?

Tags: neural-network, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[This](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/convolutional_mlp.py) code contains the following tidbit:

```
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv2d
...
# convolve input feature maps with filters
    conv_out = conv2d(
        input=input,
        filters=self.W,
        filter_shape=filter_shape,
        input_shape=image_shape
    )
```

which raises an exception due to '`input_shape`' not being found, despite being mentioned in the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/conv.html#theano.tensor.nnet.conv2d) where it says that:

> "image_shape ... – Deprecated alias for input_shape"

Looking at conv.py both locally and in the [source](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py) I found:

```
def conv2d(input, filters, image_shape=None, filter_shape=None,
       border_mode='valid', subsample=(1, 1), **kargs):
```

Needless to say, there is no trace of input_shape.
If one modifies the code above as follows

```
# convolve input feature maps with filters
    conv_out = conv2d(
        input=input,
        filters=self.W,
        filter_shape=filter_shape,
        image_shape=image_shape
    )
```

, the exception disappears and the code runs fine.

What am I missing? If `image_shape` is deprecated, how come it works while `input_shape` does not?

Is the `theano` version at the [repository](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py) obsolete?

**PS:** I would have liked to ask directly the folks at http://deeplearning.net, but I could not find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the latest version installed?

[`conv.py`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/conv.py) contains the deprecated implementation of conv2d. The new implementation can be found in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/tensor/nnet/__init__.py#L36)

Make sure you are using the import statement

```
from theano.tensor.nnet import conv2d
```

and not

```
from theano.tensor.nnet.conv import conv2d
```

since the second one is going to import the deprecated implementation

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it.